# How to make an AJAX call in WP plugin on the front end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm developing WP plugin which when user enters `ID` will get post against that `ID`. It is working fine on admin side. I've followed [this](http://dobsondev.com/2015/06/12/wordpress-ajax-example/) example to get data by AJAX call but now I'm trying to do it on the front end where anyone can enter `ID` and get a result. I've removed function which I was using to create page on admin side. Now I have 3 functions named:

1. hello_word()
2. ajax_script()
3. ajax_handler()

I've tried to use following hooks to register but it was not working

- add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ajax_script' );
- add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'ajax_script' );
- add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'ajax_script' );

`hello_word()` function contains code for text field and button. 
I call `hello_word()` function from a template file and it's being displayed correctly, but AJAX is not working when I click button. The issue I found is that `ajax_script()` is not loaded and in debugging mode in source there is nothing when I click button.

So how to load ajax function correctly, while I'm calling `hello_word()` from a template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got things mixed up a bit.

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'your_handler' );` and `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'your_handler' );` are used to add function which will handle response to your ajax call for logged in and guest users respectively.

`add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_script' );` - front end action for footer is `wp_footer` and that will work only if your theme actually call it. But it's better practice to have a separate .js file with all js for your plugin instead of outputting it inline.
To enqueue your script you can use following code

```
function enqueue_assets()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('your_plugin_js', plugins_url('/my.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), false, true); //true will put it into the footer
    wp_localize_script('your_plugin_js', 'your_plugin_ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php', ((is_ssl()) ? 'https' : 'http')))); // your url for ajax call wil be available as your_plugin_ajax_object.ajax_url
    //wp_enqueue_style('your_plugin_css', plugins_url('/my.css', __FILE__)); // you can output css here too if you want
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_assets');
```

You can call your `hello_world` function wherever you like.

Comment: if i put all js code in separate file and enqueue script , after that simple call function hello_word then ajax will work fine or i have to do something more ?

Comment: i suppose if i call hello_word function then only this function will be executed not others, or all code in that file would be executed ?

Comment: @coder `hello_world` should only return the stuff for user input. If you show me code for all 3 functions on say paste bin, I'll correct whatever needs to be corrected and will explain if you don't understand something.

Comment: actually it was working fine for admin side , here you can see that orignal code  http://pastebin.com/XvMUsfjy      i just made some changes for frond end users in  above one which is not working

Comment: It looks fine if you want to keep the inline js, though you'd have to define `ajaxurl` because on front end it will be undefined. and if you want for it to work for guests also, add `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dobsondev_ajax_tester_approal_action', 'dobsondev_ajax_tester_ajax_handler' );`

Comment: actually first i want to test it keeping inline after that i will make separate file for js

Comment: how i can define ajax url for front end , and if i use separate file for js then i have to define ajaxurl or not ?

Comment: Might as well do it properly from the start. script.js -> http://pastebin.com/w9MpFnRb , your.php -> http://pastebin.com/r8apQUEq

Comment: thanks for your nice help , just one last thing if i call dobsondev_form() function in some theme file then ajax will work for it and it will display data ?

Comment: @coder you're welcome. And yes, it will work even if `dobsondev_form()` is in theme file, for example `functions.php` and other functions are in your plugin file.

Comment: @coder You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem.